# Django module not found error, but it's been deleted and all references removed

Tags: python, django

I'm running Django 2.2, python 3.6.7 and I'm working in a virtual environment on Ubuntu 18.04.

Having done a tutorial where the project "mysite" was built, I'm now doing another exercise to build an API. I'm using the same virtualenv. However when I migrate in my new project, call it `tutorial`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'`.

So I deleted `mysite`. And I get the same error. And then I deleted the parent directory, recreated it (obviously not including mysite) and get the same error. I've searched recursively the codebase and the virtualenv and "mysite" does not turn up.

What's going on here?

Comment: Have you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`/`PYTHON_PATH`?

Comment: I feel like I should go an crawl under a rock... In an unrelated fashion would you like to put that as an answer and then I might happen to accidentally accept it...

Comment: it happens to all of us :) I have added it as answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`/`PYTHON_PATH` environment variables.