# gunicorn looking for deleted module; cannot run django application in GCP

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a django application that's been running fine on GCP, and I recently removed a dependency: `django-colorfields`.  I didn't need this functionality, so I removed these items from my models, migrated the database and uninstalled the module.

Now when I deploy my project to GCP, I can't get past the admin login page.  The admin page (`https://myproject.com/admin`) shows up just fine, but when I enter my username and password and hit enter, I get a HTTP 500 internal server error.

I checked the internal server logs, and there's a number of gunicorn errors, but this one stands out:

```
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 95, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    self.callable = self.load()
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/srv/main.py", line 1, in <module>
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    from polb_cms.wsgi import application
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/srv/polb_cms/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    application = get_wsgi_application()
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    import_module(entry)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorfield'
2023-11-09 20:02:29.950
[2023-11-09 22:02:29 -0600] [18] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

That last bit -- `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'colorfield'` -- stands out to me.  I have removed ALL references to `django-colorfield` in my entire project (I've done a find + replace in my entire project and can't find it anywhere!), but for some reason, my GCP deployed file still thinks that it needs this module and has an error every time.

My app.yaml file is dead simple:

```
# [START django_app]
# [START gaestd_py_django_app_yaml]
runtime: python311

env_variables:
  # This setting is used in settings.py to configure your ALLOWED_HOSTS
  APPENGINE_URL: https://my-project.uw.r.appspot.com/
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT: my-project
  GS_BUCKET_NAME: "my-bucket"

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
# [END gaestd_py_django_app_yaml]
# [END django_app]
```

and I've checked other common issues -- I have DEBUG=TRUE in my `settings.py` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]` just in case.  I'm still not able to log in to my admin website, and this seems like the best lead that I have at the moment.

I've removed it from `INSTALLED_APPS`, I've uninstalled it with `pip`, I'm removed every mention of it from my models, and I even deleted all of my migration files and reset my database because I found mentions of this module in there.  What else can I do to rid myself of this error?

Comment: Try this - deploy your project again to a new version and choose the option not to promote it i.e. ```gcloud app deploy --version=<new_version> --no-promote``` Then go to ```console > App Engine > Versions``` and click to open this new version in the web and try opening your ```admin``` page again and see if you still get the error. You can also try running your app locally but use ```dev_appserver.py``` to run it and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Creating an unpromoted version on the web still causes the same error.  I'm investigating `dev_appserver.py` right now.

Comment: Can you try the steps mentioned in these threads: [thread1](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/10o2sbs/after_i_uninstalled_a_module_i_get_the_error_no/) &[thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56523809/18265570) and also check if u have left any reference in [`urls.py`](http://urls.py)

Comment: @RoopaM So I went ahead and deleted the database (start from scratch) and deleted all migrations files, and reset them with a new migration.  What else should I try from thread1?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I tried using `dev_apperserver.py` but apparently it doesn't work with Windows, so I can't run it :(  Though the unpromoted version still doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Using our [patch](https://github.com/NoCommandLine/dev_appserver-python3-windows), you can run your app with ```dev_appserver.py``` on Windows. The reason I want you to run with ```dev_appserver.py``` is because it's a close representation of production and sometimes it's easier to debug stuff in local than on production (you have less errors to wade through than on production which increases the probability that you catch something or you see an error which is suppressed in Production)

Comment: You can try gcloud app deploy --no-cache